# New Teams Who Bot Actionable Messages Syntax? Undocumented O365ConnectorCard functionality?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm working with the `O365ConnectorCard` capabilities in Teams for bots and I'm trying to recreate the scrolling list of people the new Who bot can produce when you say something like `who works with jim@contoso.com?`.

[You can see what it looks like here.](https://today.collab365.community/story/microsoft-teams-new-who-bot-is-available-in-preview/)

If it is using the connector card functionality, I'm assuming that is a [Section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/card-reference#section-fields) but maybe using undocumented syntax? Additionally, the sections are clickable from the Who bot, but no matter what combination of `PotentialAction` added, I cannot get the row to have a hover and click of type `imBack`.

The [MessageCard Playground](https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/) as well doesn't have any examples that match what that Who bot can produce.

Anyone know how this was done?  Any MS folks want to post some sample JSON of what's possible but not available yet from the `Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams` NuGet package :)?  I'm currently up to v0.8.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Who bot is using the [List Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-cards#list-layout). The list layout is used to display a collection of `cards` in a stacked list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We haven't documented these new card formats yet - we were waiting for Who bot to ship, but there are actually two new card formats, PersonCard and ListCard. You can see some commented-out examples of how to use them here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/BotBuilder-MicrosoftTeams/blob/3c6f07b7600bb20713626cbf79acf5e114e57d0d/CSharp/Tests/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams.Tests.Shared/CardTests.cs.

ListCard is different from List, and there are supports for three kinds of objects in a list: Person, File, and a generic one called "resultitem" - that latter one may not render properly on Android. There's also a way to add a separator line.

This may or may not be enough to get you going, but in case you find it useful:

```js
{  
  "content":{  
    "title":"Test List Card",
    "items":[  
      {  
        "type":"section",
        "title":"List Card section"
      },
      {  
        "type":"person",
        "id":"shmayura@microsoft.com",
        "title":"Shanmathi Mayuram Krithivasan",
        "subtitle":"SOFTWARE ENGINEER",
        "tap":{  
          "type":"invoke",
          "title":"Details?",
          "value":"{\"intentName\":\"WhoIs\",\"employeeName\":null,\"employeeEmail\":\"shmayura@microsoft.com\",\"topic\":null}"
        }
      },
      {  
        "type":"file",
        "id":"https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/teams/skypespacesteamnew/Shared%20Documents/Design/FinancialReport.xlsx",
        "title":"FinancialReport",
        "subtitle":"teams > skypespacesteamnew > design",
        "tap":{  
          "type":"openUrl",
          "title":"Open url",
          "value":"https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/teams/skypespacesteamnew/Shared%20Documents/Design/FinancialReport.xlsx"
        }
      },
      {  
        "type":"resultItem",
        "title":"Seattle to Chicago",
        "subtitle":"$500 July 4 - July 8",
        "icon":"https://skypeteamsbotstorage.blob.core.windows.net/bottestartifacts/sandwich_thumbnail.png",
        "tap":{  
          "type":"imBack",
          "title":"Reply",
          "value":"flightto Chicago"
        }
      }
    ],
    "buttons":[  
      {  
        "type":"imBack",
        "title":"Open Online",
        "value":"editOnline"
      }
    ]
  },
  "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.teams.card.list"
}
```

Comment: Thank you Bill!  I’m going to give this a go. I think I’ve got enough based on the JSON above to make this work.  Cheers!

Comment: Mark, really appreciate the answer as well!